# Round NaN in Haskell

Tags: haskell, floating-point, nan

To my great surprise, I found that rounding a NaN value in Haskell returns a gigantic negative number:

```
round (0/0)
-269653970229347386159395778618353710042696546841345985910145121736599013708251444699062715983611304031680170819807090036488184653221624933739271145959211186566651840137298227914453329401869141179179624428127508653257226023513694322210869665811240855745025766026879447359920868907719574457253034494436336205824
```

The same thing happens with floor and ceiling.

What is happening here? Is this behavior intended? Of course, I understand that anyone who doesn't want this behavior can always write another function that checks isNaN - but are there existing alternative standard library functions that handle NaN more sanely (for some definition of "more sanely")?

Comment: One thing I found was that constraining `round $ 0/0 :: Integral b => b` such that `b :: Int` yields `0`, while `b :: Integer` yields the negative number.

Comment: The source of the issue is `properFraction` which is used to implement `round`, test it with: `fst $ properFraction $ (0/0 :: Double) :: Integer`. If you test with `fst $ properFraction $ (0/0 :: Float) :: Integer`, you get `-510423550381407695195061911147652317184` instead. `properFraction` is implemented here: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/master/libraries/base/GHC/Float.hs#L320-L331

Comment: Well... what is your definition of "more sanely"? What should it do instead? I honestly can't think of a good behavior for `round NaN`.

Comment: @DanielWagner an error would be more sane than returning an arbitrary number...

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice to also have a function `roundFP :: Double -> Double` which 1) can perform rounding without an intermediate integral type, and 2) can map NaN to NaN.

Comment: @chi the good news is that actually `round NaN < -Infinity`, so it would be possible to just make `fromIntegral` yield NaN again for those cases.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the bad news is that `not (round NaN > -Infinity)` ;).

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR:** `NaN` have an arbitrary representation between `2 ^ 1024` and `2 ^ 1025` (bounds not included), and `- 1.5 * 2 ^ 1024` (which is *one possible*) `NaN` happens to be the one you hit.

---

## Why any reasoning is off

> What is happening here?

You're entering the region of undefined behaviour. Or at least that is what you would call it in some other languages. The report defines `round` as follows:

> #### [6.4.6 Coercions and Component Extraction](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch6.html#x13-1350006.4.6)
>
> The `ceiling`, `floor`, `truncate`, and `round` functions each take a real fractional argument and return an integral result. … `round x` returns the nearest integer to `x`, the even integer if `x` is equidistant between two integers.

In our case `x` does not represent a number to begin with. According to 6.4.6, `y = round x` should fulfil that any other `z` from `round`'s codomain has an equal or greater distance:

```
y = round x ⇒ ∀z : dist(z,x) >= dist(y,x)
```

However, the distance (aka the subtraction) of numbers is defined only for, well, numbers. If we used

```
dist n d = fromIntegral n - d
```

we get in trouble soon: any operation that includes `NaN` will return `NaN` again, and comparisons on `NaN` fail, so our property above **does not hold for any** `z` if `x` was a `NaN` to begin with. If we check for `NaN`, we can return any value, but then our property **holds for all pairs**:

```
dist n d = if isNaN d then constant else fromIntegral n - d
```

So we're completely arbitrary in what `round x` shall return if `x` was not a number.

## Why do we get that large number regardless?

"OK", I hear you say, "that's all fine and dandy, but why do I get that number?" That's a good question.

> Is this behavior intended?

Somewhat. It isn't really intended, but to be expected. First of all, we have to know how `Double` works.

### IEE 754 double precision floating point numbers

A `Double` in Haskell is usually a IEEE 754 compliant double precision floating point number, that is a number that has 64 bits and is represented with

```
x = s * m * (b ^ e)
```

where `s` is a single bit, `m` is the mantissa (52 bits) and `e` is the exponent (11 bits, `floatRange`). `b` is the base, and its usually `2` (you can check with `floadRadix`). Since the value of `m` is normalized, every well-formed `Double` has a unique representation.

### IEEE 754 NaN

Except `NaN`. `NaN` is represented as the e<sub>max</sub>+1, ***as well as a non-zero mantissa***. So if the bitfield

```
SEEEEEEEEEEEMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
```

represents a `Double`, what's a valid way to represent `NaN`?

```
?111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
            ^
```

That is, a single `M` is set to `1`, the other are not necessary to set this notion. The sign is arbitrary. Why only a single bit? Because its sufficient.

### Interpret NaN as `Double`

Now, when we ignore the fact that this is a malformed `Double`—a `NaN`– and really, *really*, ***really*** want to interpret it as number, what number would we get?

```
m = 1.5
e = 1024

x = 1.5 * 2 ^ 1024
  = 3 * 2 ^ 1024 / 2
  = 3 * 2 ^ 1023
```

And lo and behold, that's exactly the number you get for `round (0/0)`:

```
ghci> round $ 0 / 0
-269653970229347386159395778618353710042696546841345985910145121736599013708251444699062715983611304031680170819807090036488184653221624933739271145959211186566651840137298227914453329401869141179179624428127508653257226023513694322210869665811240855745025766026879447359920868907719574457253034494436336205824
ghci> negate $ 3 * 2 ^ 1023
-269653970229347386159395778618353710042696546841345985910145121736599013708251444699062715983611304031680170819807090036488184653221624933739271145959211186566651840137298227914453329401869141179179624428127508653257226023513694322210869665811240855745025766026879447359920868907719574457253034494436336205824
```

Which brings our small adventure to a halt. We have a `NaN`, which yields a `2 ^ 1024`, and we have some non-zero mantissa, which yields a result with absolute value between `2 ^ 1024 < x < 2 ^ 1025`.

Note that this isn't the only way `NaN` can get represented:

> In IEEE 754, NaNs are often represented as floating-point numbers with the exponent e<sub>max</sub> + 1 and nonzero significands. Implementations are free to put system-dependent information into the significand. Thus there is not a unique NaN, but rather a whole family of NaNs.

For more information, see the [classic paper on floating point numbers by Goldberg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: As cool as this explanation is, I think it fails to capture the issue here. Bottom line: `round` is a partial function, and it's meaningless to return an answer. So, it should throw an error. Just like integer division by zero does.

Comment: It's worth remembering that when `round` was originally written the IEEE standard was not yet prevalent and many computers used other formats, lacking NaN.

Comment: @LeventErkok  why should `round` throw? Why shouldn't `0/0` throw in order to make sure that a `Double` is never `NaN`? After all, that's the behaviour with `div x 0` or `x % 0`. IIRC, early floating point implementations even just HALTed in that case (greetings from the 90s).  That being said, the report isn't clear on the semantics of `Double`, it just tells us that it's a double precision floating point number, which _usually_  includes (silent) `NaN`, but an implementation might as well use signalling `NaN`s, which would remove the problem in `round` completely.

Comment: @augustss wasn't `round` written in a time when FPUs were still separately sold and not part of your usual CPU (yet), unless you had a lot of money to spend?

Comment: @Zeta: A double can be a `NaN`. If you buy into IEEE754, that *is* the semantics you have to support. There's neither a choice nor a question there. The issue here is that `round` says it'll give you an `Integral` value, and there's just no good value to map `NaN` to, as you aptly observed yourself. A better type of `round` would be to return a `Maybe` value; barring that, you have no option but to throw an exception. Also, Lennart is quite right that some of these functions do predate IEEE754 itself, so there's historical perspective here too. But that doesn't justify doing the wrong thing.

Comment: @LeventErkok I don't justify `round`'s behaviour, I just try to explain it. I'm aware of those issues and pointing to more. Even without `NaN`, `round` returns wrong results if the `Integral` is too small, e.g. `round 10e60 :: Int`. An exception in `round` would be adequate at the moment, since it follows the behaviour of `div x 0` or `succ maxBound` and other, seemingly total functions. But that leaves the domain of "why do I get the result I get" and enters the world of "what should actually happen in a better implementation" :).

Answer (score 2):

This has long been observed as a problem. Here're a few tickets filed against GHC on this very topic:

- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3070
- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/11553
- https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/3676

Unfortunately, this is a thorny issue with lots of ramifications. My personal belief is that this is a genuine bug and it should be fixed properly by throwing an error. But you can read the comments on these tickets to get an understanding of the tricky issues preventing GHC from implementing a proper solution. Essentially, it comes down to speed vs. correctness, and this is one point where (i) the Haskell report is woefully underspecified, and (ii) GHC compromises the latter for the former.